# Write 2 line of textstream to one Access record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code which reads a text file and writes to an Access table if a value (N1) is found

```
    Do While Not objStream.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objStream.ReadLine
        ReDim MyArray(0)
        MyArray = Split(strLine, ",")
        If MyArray(0)= "N1" Then
            rs.AddNew
            rs("Field1") = MyArray(0)
            rs("Field2") = MyArray(1)
            rs.Update
        End If
    Loop
```

I'd like to know if it's posible, before writing to the database, to check the next line of the textstream and if the value N2 is found, then also write this to the record

So if my sample text file data is...

```
N1 Cat
N2 Cat
N1 Dog
N1 Fish
N2 Fish
N1 Hamster
N2 Hamster
```

...my expected output to Access would be :-

```
Field 1 Field 2 Field 3 Field 4
N1      Cat     N2      Cat
N1      Dog
N1      Fish    N2      Fish
N1      Hamster N2      Hamster
```

I've looked up the textstream object and can't find a method to read the next line.

Comment: Just store the previous line in an additional array and dump into 2 lines if both rows are N1 and into one line with N2 in fields 3 and 4

Comment: What if the array starts with N2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need:

A buffer is used to store the pre-read line if necessary.

```
'Definition of the buffer
Dim buffer As String
'Now also check if the buffer is filled
Do While (Not objStream.AtEndOfStream) Or (Len(buffer) > 0)
    'If the buffer is filled, use and clear it, instead read next line 
    If Len(buffer) > 0 Then
        strLine = buffer
        buffer = vbNullString
    Else
        strLine = objStream.ReadLine
    End If
    ReDim MyArray(0)
    MyArray = Split(strLine, ",")
    If MyArray(0)= "N1" Then
        rs.AddNew
        rs("Field1") = MyArray(0)
        rs("Field2") = MyArray(1)
        'Read a line to the buffer and check if it starts with 'N2'
        buffer = objStream.ReadLine
        If buffer Like "N2*" Then
            'Use the content of the buffer, store it in Field3 and 4, and clear it
            MyArray = Split(buffer, ",")
            buffer = vbNullString
            rs("Field3") = MyArray(0)
            rs("Field4") = MyArray(1)
        End If
        rs.Update
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like so, not sure if it's the best method.

```
Sub c()

Dim f As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim t As Scripting.TextStream
Dim a() As String
Dim n1() As String
Dim n2() As String
Dim l As Long
Dim rs As Object

Set f = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set t = f.OpenTextFile("C:\Workspace\Dummy Data\dummy.txt", ForReading)

a = Split(t.ReadAll, vbCrLf)

t.Close

For l = 0 To UBound(a)

    n1 = Split(a(l), " ")

    If n1(0) = "N1" Then

        rs.addnew
        rs("Field1") = n1(0)
        rs("Field2") = n1(1)

        If l + 1 < UBound(a) Then
            n2 = Split(a(l + 1), " ")
            If n2(0) = "N2" Then
                rs("Field3") = n2(0)
                rs("Field4") = n2(1)
            End If
            l = l + 1
        End If

        rs.Update
        Erase n1
        Erase n2

    End If

Next l

erase a


End Sub
```